# Does a returned Json response preserve insertion order of a List?

Tags: json, jackson, spring-data-jpa

When returning a entity containing a array list property, as a Json response via a GET operation through a rest controller, will the Json response being returned preserve the insertion order of that array list?

The entity is fetched from a postgresql database, using spring-data-jpa.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private final List<SomeObj> myList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

What if it's a Set? Do I need to use a SortedSet to make sure that the order is preserved in the returned response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jackson` for collection serialization uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer` class or other similar which uses `Iterator` returned by given collection to traverse it. So, by default it preserves insertion order if collection preserves it. If you use `Jackson` with `Hibernate` do not forget to register [HibernateXModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) module.